# I need a Arabic analyzer for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

im doing a elasticsearch work for Arabic areas,so if you guys have a Arabic analyzer or a good way to analysis Arabic (my friend's way is that translate Arabic to English,then analysis English and searh it,finally translate the English result to Arabic.it works, but i think its not good ),please tell me ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't [`arabic`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#arabic-analyzer) analyzer fit for you?

Comment: em...i do not have a good Arabic analyzer yet. im looking for it, but i dont find it at present

Comment: Why default arabic analyzer doesn't work for you? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#arabic-analyzer

Comment: yeah ,but im worried about that it doesn't work quite accurately,you know .like Chinese  ,it has a more accurate analyzer and it is undependent, named Ik-analyzer. i just have the worry and wanna study your experience before i do it.

Comment: How about the stanford corenlp? https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP